# Problems with import dxf files

Tags: import

I'm having a problem to import 3D dxf files from AutoCAD. DXF importer is enabled. Nothing happens when I click on the dxf files to import.
Anything I'm still missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! can you maybe share a link to this dxf file?

Comment: If you can't release your main model, please share a toy example that's failing.

Comment: Hello guys. Thank you for the reply. No problems to share. Here is the link:

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/jw4n6hw6uhiufm2w6o55i/NC3MDX-TOP_Final.dxf?rlkey=tuganqw5vkeqlpt7uhn3clsjc&dl=0

Comment: Basically, even simple drawing fails to import.